# Как вычислить сумму и разницу значений строк в Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: tab]

Есть два случая, в 1-ом когда code_card один и тот же необходимо суммировать две строки; во 2-ом когда code_card разный необходима разница между ними. Интересует только две последние строки

Comment: Вы не знаете про оператор CASE?

Comment: А как сделать разницу между строками?

Comment: `val - LAG(val)` и соответственно `LEAD(val) - val`.

Comment: Спасибо большое)!